# use wrapper to center a nav ul

Tags: html, css

I'm using a < nav>< ul>< li> to make a menu. I want to put it horizontally and center the whole UL, but it looks that it doesn't work, the ul isn't centered with a margin-auto on a wrapper

```
<div id="wrap">
<nav>
<ul>
    <li class="menuitem">Menu</li>
    <li class="menuitem">Menu</li>
    <li class="menuitem">Menu</li>
    <li class="menuitem">Menu</li>
    <li class="menuitem">Menu</li>
</ul>
```

```
    .menuitem {
background-color: #E3E3E3;
float: left;
width: 100px;
height: 90px;
list-style-type: none;
text-align: center;
color: black;
display: inline;
}

#wrap {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=Qttzbi9GJ9)

Comment: `display: inline-block;` on your `.menu_nav ul li`. Your updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/84exq/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should give your `.menu-nav` a fixed width, for example `width: 200px;` otherwise `margin: auto` doesnt work.

also you have the `text-align: center;` attribute in your `.menuitem` class.
This centers the text.
Delete that if you dont want the text centered within the menu.

---

To get more information about more advanced centering methods in css, read this [blog post about css centering](http://jackrimell.co.uk/centering-in-css-old-and-new/)

Comment: thanks! The text-align is to center the text inside the li because there is a img on the li too, all centered :-)